# How to add an "id" to each column in .arff file for k-means clustering in weka

Tags: java, weka, k-means

This is my arff file (links.arff) :

```
@relation links

@attribute isLink1Present numeric
@attribute isLink2Present numeric
@attribute isLink3Present numeric
@attribute isLink4Present numeric
@attribute isLink6Present numeric
@attribute isLink7Present numeric
@attribute isLink8Present numeric
@attribute isLink9Present numeric

@data
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0
1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0
1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0
1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0
1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0
1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0
1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0
1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0
1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0
1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0
```

Here is how I'm implementing k-means :

```
public void runKMeans(int numClusters){
    try {
        SimpleKMeans kmeans = new SimpleKMeans();

        //DistanceFunction df = new weka.core.ManhattanDistance();
        DistanceFunction df = new weka.core.EuclideanDistance();

        kmeans.setDistanceFunction(df);
        kmeans.setSeed(10);

        kmeans.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true);
        kmeans.setNumClusters(numClusters);

        String arffFile = new PropertyUtils().getProperty("datafiles-home")+"\\links.arff";
        DataSource source = new DataSource(arffFile);
        Instances instances = source.getDataSet();

        //inst.setDataset(instances);
        kmeans.buildClusterer(instances);
        System.out.println(kmeans.displayStdDevsTipText());

        // This array returns the cluster number (starting with 0) for each instance
        // The array has as many elements as the number of instances
        int[] assignments = kmeans.getAssignments();

        int i=0;

        List<Cluster> lc = new ArrayList<Cluster>();
        for(int clusterNum : assignments) {
            lc.add(new Cluster((i+1) , clusterNum));
          //  System.out.println("Instance "+(i+1)+" -> Cluster "+clusterNum);
            i++;

        }
        Collections.sort(lc);

        for(Cluster c : lc){
            PrintUtils.println("Instance : "+c.getInstance()+" Cluster "+c.getCluster());
        }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I would like to associate each column of data with a "name" attribute so I can then identify each column. How can I accomplish this ? I don't think I can add a String attribute to @data as this will bread the k-means algorithm implementation ? Is there another method ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may add an additional attribute for naming the instances.

Then, for `EuclideanDistance`, you may use `-R` option or `setAttributeIndices` to decide the range of attributes to be used in the calculation of the distance. Remove `name` attribute will work!